# Filename containing carriage return on Windows is not recognised by Python

Tags: python, windows, carriage-return

I would like to select a file, but the filename contains a *carriage return* and so `.isfile()` constantly returns `False`. While when I use `.fnmatch()` it prints the filename including the trailing *carriage return*.

```py
import fnmatch
import os
local_path = 'd:'+os.sep
filename = '1F80813965EDAA4FC5BA44A91E0DBFF1'
local_file = os.path.join(local_path, filename+'\r')

print( os.path.isfile(local_file) ) 
# Returns False

for file in os.listdir(local_path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, filename+'?'):
        print(repr(file)) 
        # Returns 'd:\\1F80813965EDAA4FC5BA44A91E0DBFF1\r'
```

What is the problem here? Is it Windows? Is it the NTFS partition? Or does the `os.path.join()` function not understand `'\r'`?

Comment: How did you create that file? Because Windows doesn't allow [special characters in filename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file). If you copied the file from another system, this may be a problem.

Comment: Yes, the file was created on Linux.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you might be able to use the file ID to get around the invalid name. Open the directory (`CreateFile` with backup semantics) and call `GetFileInformationByHandleEx` on the directory handle to query the `FileIdBothDirectoryInfo`. Search for the filename in the results and get its `FileId`. Open the file using the directory handle and file ID via `OpenFileById`. Finally, fix the invalid name by calling `SetFileInformationByHandle` to set the `FileRenameInfo` with a valid name. Use the directory handle again as the `RootDirectory` for the rename.

Comment: This assumes `OpenFileById` and setting the rename information won't freak out for no good reason about the invalid name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't allow [special characters in filename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions):

> [...]
>
> - Use a backslash (\) to separate the *components of a path*. The backslash divides the file name from the path to it, and one directory name from another directory name in a path. You cannot use a backslash in the name for the actual file or directory because it is a reserved character that separates the names into components.
>
> [...]
>
> - Use any character in the current code page for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255), except for the following:
>
>   - The following reserved characters:
>
>     - < (less than)
>     - > greater than)
>     - : (colon)
>     - " (double quote)
>     - / (forward slash)
>     - \ (backslash)
>     - | (vertical bar or pipe)
>     - ? (question mark)
>     - * (asterisk)
>   - Integer value zero, sometimes referred to as the ASCII NUL character.
>   - Characters whose integer representations are in the range from 1 through 31, except for alternate data streams where these characters are allowed. For more information about file streams, see [File Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-streams).
>   - Any other character that the target file system does not allow.

If you copied the file from another system, this may be a problem. If you need to use this file in Windows, you would probably need to rename it before copying.

Comment: To be clear, some of this is specific to Microsoft's general-use file systems, which includes the NTFS filesystem driver, so I'm not contradicting you with regard to the OP's case. The characters that are almost universally reserved are null, slash, backslash, and the five wildcard characters: asterisk, question mark, less than sign (`DOS_STAR`), greater than sign (`DOS_QM`), and double quote (`DOS_DOT`). A permissive example is a VirtualBox shared folder, which allows colon, pipe, and control characters 1-31. A totally permissive example is the named-pipe filesystem, which allows everything.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the following line is creating a path to file. You can try to remove `\r` in it.

```
local_file = os.path.join(local_path, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Without luck I've tried to remove the `'\r'`, and I've also tried with `'\n'`, `'\r\n'` and a blank space `' '` instead. It always returns `False`.